# thunderbird 86.0b.1 can't locate other applications

Tags: firefox, thunderbird

Somehow I got a new version of Thunderbird altho' I don't recall seeing it listed in the latest software update.  (I am running 20.04.2.)  It is apparently a beta version.  It was installed in snap which is where my previous version was installed.  However, the previous version was able to launch Firefox from links in messages and this version is not.  This version does not seem to find any apps that can follow an html link.  If I navigate to Firefox in Choose application, Thunderbird just shows me the Choose app dialog again.

Since this version tweaked the profile, I can't use the profile in an older version so downgrade is not an option.  What to do?

As an aside, the Tbird help screen says that I am on the beta update channel and I have no idea how that came about.  Was this included in Ubuntu updates that made available in the last couple of days?

EDIT:  I have done all installs/updates/upgrades of software through the gui Software & Updates app that came with Ubuntu.  That app states that snaps are checked routinely and updated automatically.

Comment: "*Tbird help screen says that I am on the beta update channel and I have no idea how that came about. Was this included in Ubuntu updates*" Ubuntu Updates are deb-only. beta-update-channel is snap-only. They are completely unrelated. It's like your alarm clock and your toothbrush: You use them both every morning, but they have nothing to do with each other and often live in separate rooms.

Answer (score 0):

Snaps are not debs. Snaps are *different*.  Snaps don't show among your deb updates. Snaps *automatically* upgrade silently. That's one of their big features.

When you chose to install the Thunderbird snap, you were perhaps unwise to choose 'Beta' -- that means you WANT to be a tester and discover problems and file bug reports.

Advice: Thunderbird is unable to follow HTML links seems like a bug. Please report it: https://snapcraft.io/forum.

Suggestion for downgrading to the 'Stable" channel: Backup your Profile data. Then try [creating a new Profile, and copy your data into it](https://support.cdn.mozilla.net/en-US/kb/profiles-where-thunderbird-stores-user-data).

Comment: I did not "choose" Beta.  I installed TB 84 when I had 18.04 back in February 2020 and it was NOT THE BETA version.  It appears to have been upgraded to 86 beta  by Ubuntu software updater since I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 but not right away.  It was still 84 through the month of January.  The change to 86beta occurred at the beginning of last week.